# Streaming on Ruby Thin server

Tags: ruby, streaming, rack, thin, eventmachine

I tried the following ruby code...

```
 self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"
 self.response.headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"
 self.response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.ctime.to_s
 self.response_body =  Rack::Chunked::Body.new(Enumerator.new do |y|
   10.times do

     sleep 1
     y << "Hello World\n"
   end
 end)
```

This works great in Unicron server but can't stream using Thin server. I tried 1.5.0 and 2.0.0.pre too, this is not working in thin.

I tried the following rack code,

```
class DeferredBody
  def each(block)
    @server_block = block
  end

  def send(data)
    @server_block.call data
  end
end

class RackStreamApp
  def self.call(env)
    Thread.new do
      sleep 2  # simulate waiting for some event
      body = DeferredBody.new
      response = [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, body]
      env['async.callback'].call response

      body.send 'Hello, '
      sleep 2
      body.send 'World'
    end

    [-1, {}, []]  # or throw :async
  end
end
```

The above code streams "Hello, World" if we use Unicorn Server, but the code doesn't stream using Thin server 1.5.0 ( I tried 2.0.0-pre too)

Is there anything I can do to stream data using the thin server?

Comment: Have you tried [Rack::Stream](https://github.com/intridea/rack-stream)?

Comment: I tried Rack::Stream but there is a problem requiring the gem. Please suggest a way using the above code.

Comment: First of all, try to figure out how `DeferredBody` is populated with `@server_block` variable. Looking at the code I have no idea.

Comment: Second, using `Thread` and `sleep` is generally a very bad idea. You're using an eventmachine enabled server, so please use `EM.add_timer` or whatever better fits your task.

Comment: If you're just trying to mimic examples from [this](http://polycrystal.org/2012/04/15/asynchronous_responses_in_rack.html) post, consider the one that is titled 'Signaling deferred body with Thin'.